# Numba in Python for faster code execution uses only one core

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numba, eigenvector

I have been trying to use `numba` in python to make a specific python script run faster.

I have read the `numba` documentation about the supported `numpy` functions and I have modified my code so that it is compatible [the documentation is here](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html).

**However, it seems (after using `top` that only 1 core is used).**

My code is this and estimates the largest `k` eigenvectors of a matrix (that is not built explicitly) using `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator` and `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh`.

```
import numpy as np, scipy
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs,eigsh
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import jit
from scipy import stats

def standardize(X):
    X = stats.zscore(X, axis =1, ddof=1)
    return X

@jit(nopython=True)
def Binline(x):
    # transpose() is supported by numba
    tmp1 = np.dot(X.transpose(), x) 
    # np.dot() and np.divide() is supported by numba
    y = np.divide(np.dot(X,tmp1) , (T-1.0) )
    return y

X = np.random.rand(10000,500)
X = standardize(X)
T = X.shape[1]

# Pass the above inline function into a Linear Operator 
A = LinearOperator(shape=(X.shape[0], X.shape[0]) , matvec =  Binline)

print("starting")
k = 400 # how many eigenvectors to estimate
vals1, vecs1 = eigsh(A, k=k, which='LA', ncv=2*k, maxiter=2500, tol=1e-14)
print("finished")

# sorting
idx = vals1.argsort()[::-1]
vals1, vecs1 = vals1[idx], vecs1[:,idx]
print("all done")
```

I would expect that all available cores on my system are used.
Any tip/help would be much appreciated.

**System specs:**

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       527842404 kB
MemFree:        359609816 kB
MemAvailable:   413678484 kB
Buffers:          106068 kB
Cached:         56403884 kB
SwapCached:        15596 kB
Active:         107761496 kB
Inactive:       57753936 kB

$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              96
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-95
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  24
Socket(s):           2
NUMA node(s):        2
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               85
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8160 CPU @ 2.10GHz
Stepping:            4
CPU MHz:             3615.553
BogoMIPS:            4200.00

>>> np.show_config()
mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/include']
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/Open_Soft/anaconda3/include']
```

Comment: Why numba? Assuming, that your computation is dominated by your matrix-vector products, just use a sane numpy-setup with a parallelized BLAS-backend (OpenBLAS, MKL). Then `.dot` exploits that for free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `numba` is the most user friendly module that I have found and in theory it is make just for cases like mine. I would expect it to ru smoothly using all my cores.

Comment: It will never compete with BLAS for a simple matrix-vec product.

Comment: Is is possible to provide an example about how to tailor my code for usage with BLAS?

Comment: `np.dot` will do that automatically (at least in pure numpy-code; not sure what an outer @jit will do). Look for some related questions on how to read out your numpy-config to reason about your BLAS-backend. Many ways of installing numpy provide out-of-box parallelized BLAS (Anaconda with MKL, Ubuntu with OpenBLAS; at least that's the state i remember)

Comment: @serafeim will your real-world use-cases rely on **sparse-matrix** representations of X? Is that X further polymorphic as per dtype(s) the jit-decorated functions have to process? What are your target levels of performance ~ [us] / 1MB of data in fully-orthogonal-matrix ( i.e. w/o the effects of a sparse-representation's savings )

Comment: No sure about the sparse-matrix representations of X. X in real case example wil contain float64

Comment: I wouldn't expect `numba` to improve performance here. In any case, whether or not multiple cores will be used depends on your numpy installation and the BLAS backend. You should be able to get the configuration programatically and share it here. Also, your system information would be helpful

Comment: Sure. How can I get the configuration programatically ?

Comment: @serafeim `np.show_config()`

Comment: I posted all the information about my system

Comment: not sure how to interpret this output though